# Bibliography not shown, citations remain question marks

Tags: bibliographies, citing, texmaker

My situation is the following: 
I have two files in the same folder: `basics.tex` and `bibliography.bib`.
In Texmaker, when I select the `basics.tex` file and run LaTeX, then BibTeX, and then LaTeX again twice, I don't get any errors, and basics.pdf looks fine, except for the sources from bibliography.bib being nowhere in the pdf, and all the citations being replaced by question marks.

The `basics.tex` file begins as such (with each `\` starting on a new line):

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{slashbox}                                                                                                                           
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

In the text, there are a lot of \cite{citation}, and the bottom of basics.tex looks like this (again, with each \ starting on a new line):

\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

The `bibliography.bib` file just includes a list of all of my sources, in formats such as (with each point on a new line):

```
@book{citation,
 title={title},
 author={author},
 isbn={isbn},
 lccn={lccn},
 year={year},
 publisher={publisher}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you can get properly formatted code by highlighting the block using your mouse, then clicking on the `{}` icon above the question (or answer) box.  for in-line code, begin and end the string with a backtick.

Comment: regarding the failure to have a citation referenced, your code looks good, and so does the description of your processing.  i don't use texmaker, so can't say what might be going wrong, but try to figure out where to look for a `.bbl` file.  (it should be in the same area as the `.bib` file after running bibtex.)  if there isn't one, then something *has* gone wrong with the bibtex run.

Comment: Off-topic but still relevant: (i) The `subfigure` package is badly deprecated and shouldn't be use anymore. Consider using either `subfig` or `subcaption`. (ii) The `slashbox` package is also deprecated; consider using `diagbox` instead. (iii) Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, consider using `unsrtnat` instead of `unsrt` as the bibliography style. That way, the contents of the `isbn` field won't be ignored. (iv) Is your tex file really encoded in `latin1`? Are you sure it's not utf8-encoded?

Comment: Yes, there is a basics.bbl file in the same folder as the other two files.

Comment: WIth regards to the packages and the encoding, I'll definitely look into that!

Comment: What's in the file `basics.bbl`?

Comment: That file starts with \begin{thebibliography}{10}, and then goes on to list the sources from bibliography.bib, in a format that looks like this:  \bibitem{citation}
Firstname Lastname.
\newblock \emph{Title}.
\newblock Type, Year.
\newblock
  \url{URL}
  [Comment]. The file ends with \end{thebibliography}.

Comment: Is there any news here?